# Must Apple facilitate transfer of app purchases from one user account to another?

Tags: intellectual-property, software, england-and-wales, licensing, european-union

A recent question addresses EU law allowing the resale of software licenses. I asked on that answer, “ Does this mean that you could transfer one-time or subscription purchases of apps from mobile app stores from one account to another and that Apple must allow and facilitate this?”

How does this apply to App Store purchases?